# Design Matrix for a Bradley Terry Model

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, bradley-terry-model

I am working on a problem using a Bradley Terry Model and was asked to derive the design matrix of for this model applied to some data, but I am not sure how to do this using this data. Are there any examples or references on applying the bradley terry model and extracting the design matrix?

The data I am using comes from the BradleyTerry2 package in R, and contains information about the wins and losses of several mlb baseball teams in the 1987 season. [image]

I am attempting to write the $21×7$ model matrix $X$ for the Bradley-Terry model using this data.

So since the data has 7 total teams I feel the columns are associated to each team, and 21 refers to the rows are the total number of pairs for the 7 competitors. I know I should compute the $\pi_{i,j}$ the probability that the ith team beats the jith team, but just confused as to how to obtain these values. I am viewing this a logit model, where: $\log(\frac{\pi_{ij}}{1-\pi_{ij}})=\theta_i-\theta_j$.

Comment: The model matrix is more complex than you suppose, because it must include terms to distinguish the home team from the visitors -- and how it does depends on how you specifically wish to model the home team advantage, giving multiple valid solutions.  But if you ignore that and just summarize wins and losses, the model matrix can be written as a $\binom{7}{2}\times(7-1)=21\times 6$ matrix.

Answer (score 3):

The Bradley-Terry model supposes the log odds (*aka* the *logit*) of the chance that team $i$ beats team $j$ is the difference of a parameter $\lambda_i$ and a parameter $\lambda_j:$

$$\operatorname{logit}(\Pr(i\text{ beats }j)) = \lambda_i - \lambda_j.\tag{*}$$

Because there are as many indices as teams, but only differences are involved, the number of independent parameters is one less than the number of teams.

**The model matrix has one column for each independent parameter.**

The convention of the `R` package you reference is to set $\lambda_1 = 0,$ leaving $\lambda_2, \ldots$ to be estimated.

There are many ways to represent the outcomes of a set of competitions, but the most compact is to record how many times team $i$ beat team $j \ne i$ and how many times team $j$ beat team $i.$  This requires $\binom{d}{2}$ counts for $d$ teams.

**The model matrix $M$ in this compact representation therefore has $\binom{d}{d} = d(d-1)/2$ rows.**

Writing $\lambda = (\lambda_2, \lambda_3, \ldots, \lambda_d)^\prime$ for the column vector of parameters to be estimated, by definition of "model matrix" the formula $(*)$ must be equivalent to $M\lambda.$

---

As an example, the vignette for `BradleyTerry2` (see the reference below) opens with an analysis of journal citations, summarized by the `citations` table:

```
              citing
cited          Biometrika Comm Statist JASA JRSS-B
  Biometrika          714          730  498    221
  Comm Statist         33          425   68     17
  JASA                320          813 1072    142
  JRSS-B              284          276  325    188
```

It then converts this to the compact representation

```
      journal1     journal2 win1 win2
1   Biometrika Comm Statist  730   33
2   Biometrika         JASA  498  320
3   Biometrika       JRSS-B  221  284
4 Comm Statist         JASA   68  813
5 Comm Statist       JRSS-B   17  276
6         JASA       JRSS-B  142  325
```

Consequently the model matrix (giving the coefficients of $\lambda$) can be represented as this matrix

```
                            Biometrika Comm Statist JASA JRSS-B
Biometrika vs. Comm Statist          1           -1    0      0
Biometrika vs. JASA                  1            0   -1      0
Biometrika vs. JRSS-B                1            0    0     -1
Comm Statist vs. JASA                0            1   -1      0
Comm Statist vs. JRSS-B              0            1    0     -1
JASA vs. JRSS-B                      0            0    1     -1
```

*with one of its columns dropped.*

When I feed this matrix (without its first column) to the workhorse GLM function in `R`, using the standard `binomial` family I obtain this summary:

```
Call:  glm(formula = f, family = binomial(), data = X)

Coefficients:
`Comm Statist`            JASA        `JRSS-B`  
       -2.9491         -0.4796          0.2690  

Degrees of Freedom: 6 Total (i.e. Null);  3 Residual
Null Deviance:      1925 
Residual Deviance: 4.293    AIC: 46.39
```

As you can see, apart from using better names for the parameters, it is *identical* to the output of `BTm`:

[image]

The following is the `R` code I used for this example, constructed to apply to any `table` obect (like `citations`).

```
library(BradleyTerry2)
(citations) # Print this table
#
# Create the model matrix.
#
journals <- colnames(citations)
d <- length(journals)
d2 <- choose(d, 2)
ij <- combn(d, 2)
rows <- apply(combn(journals, 2), 2, paste, collapse = " vs. ")
M <- matrix(0, d2, d, dimnames = list(rows, journals)) # Initialize to 0
M[cbind(seq_len(d2), ij[1, ])] <- 1                    # Each winner codes as 1
M[cbind(seq_len(d2), ij[2, ])] <- -1                   # Each loser codes as -1
#
# Create a data frame.
#
i <- lower.tri(citations)
X <- cbind(as.data.frame(M), 
           Wins = t(citations)[i],
           Losses = citations[i])
#
# Specify the formula.
#
f <- as.formula(paste0("cbind(Wins, Losses) ~ `", paste(journals[-1], collapse = "` + `"), "` -1"))
(model.matrix(f, X)) # Print the model matrix.
#
# Fit the model.
# NB: when playing `a` + `b` games independently, the total number of wins
#     for team `i` will be Binomial(a+b, p) where `p` is the chance team `i` 
#
(fit <- glm(f, family = binomial(), X)) # Print basic output
```

#### Reference

David Firth. **Bradley-Terry Models in R: The BradleyTerry2 Package.**
For BradleyTerry2 version 1.1-2, 2020-02-02
https://github.com/hturner/BradleyTerry2

Answer (score 0):

Because, we are doing pairwise comparisons, the number of columns will be the individual teams and each row is one pairwise comparison, using the model that is given the first row will look like below.

$\begin{matrix} & MIL & DET & TOR & NY & BOS & CLE & BAL \\\ MILvsDET & (1 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0) \end{matrix} $

and subsequently we will have 21 comparisons using the table we can compute which team defeated the other out of the number of games played.