# Logistic regression data with reversed matches

Tags: regression, logistic, classification, binary-data

I am new at using logistic regression for binary classification problems, but am interested in using it to help determine winners and losers in this year's March Madness tournament. I have data arranged in a similar fashion to how it is in [this blog](https://rpubs.com/nimondong/march-madness-predictions), with "Team1" and information about its game stats along with "Team2" and its game stats and a result (Team1 won = 1; Team1 lost = 0). However, I also have the reverse: "Team2" and its game stats, "Team1" and its game stats and a result (Team2 won = 1; Team2 lost = 0).

My question is: is there any concern that this data is a mere mirror image of itself? In other words, the same information can be found in what essentially amounts to a duplicate record with the result reversed? Alternatively, I could have records without these "duplicates" but then only wins (result = 1) would be present, which seems lopsided.

Comment: Search our site for posts about "ELO" and the "Bradley Terry model."  I recently posted an illustration of the latter at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/641815/919.